how to make time changes while the compiler is running?
I am trying to generate random prime numbers without using stand() or rand() functions. I want to generate random numbers with the function that generates time in seconds as random values then check if it's prime or not if it's not prime then run the function that generates time again with different values.
The code gets me a Segmentation fault while its not prime :(
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int RandomGenerator (int long);
long int PrimeChecker (int long);

int main() {
    std::cout<<RandomGenerator (time(NULL));
}

int RandomGenerator (int long num)
{
    return PrimeChecker ( (num * 88 + 67) % 100000);
}

long int PrimeChecker (int long digit)
{
    for ( int i = 2 ; i < digit/2 ; i++)
    {
        if (digit % i == 0 ) RandomGenerator(time(NULL));
    }
    return digit;
}

Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

Check out the example in std::uniform_int_distribution.

This is a stack overflow: RandomGenerator calls PrimeChecker calls RandomGenerator ...

time(NULL) will only change once every second. If for a given second the result of PrimeChecker is false it will continue to be false for the rest of that second. When this happens your algorithm keeps adding functions to the call stack in a loop, leading to a likely stack overflow.

Your RandomGenerator is reimplementing the standard feature https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/linear_congruential_engine.

Aside: long int mixed with int long? And missing from one place? yuck

And the call to RandomGenerator in PrimeChecker is discarded entirely.

What you should do is create a list of prime numbers up front (compile time, or read from file) and pick one random prime number from that list. Computing prime numbers on the fly is very inefficient (e.g. load one of the file from here : https://naturalnumbers.org/primes.html)

Problem description is very poor. Title is even worse. I suspect that question suffers form XY problem. What kind of functionality (from end user perspective) do you need to achieve?

Even if the stack was big enough, this code is wrong. PrimeChecker() will return the first given digit in the end because you do not use the return value of RandomGenerator() (it is discarded). You should have assigned it to digit and restart the loop from the very beginning with the new digit value. In other words, that recursion is wrong and unneeded :)

I would recommend watching this: rand() Considered Harmful

https://wandbox.org/permlink/ODZ2TL4VgjJv6b0c

@MarekR It's "sieve" not "sive" :p

The title says "while compiling", but the question is about run-time.  Which is it?
